# Does Workfront API have an OAuth2 (or similar) based authentication?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, workfront-api

I have a web application and need to authenticate users but I do not want users enter their Workfront login credentials in our webapp but want that do be done in Workfront. And after that get a confirmation (token / along with user data) from Workfront whether authentication was successful or not.

For example, user enters our webapp, presses Login button. Web app then redirects a user to Workfront where user authenticates itself and then Workfront redirects user back to our web application (or we get authentication response back via javascript library) - so at the end our web app gets back user data with a token / data or failure information.

Is that possible with Workfront API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Workfront API to take a username/password and be returned a session ID but you can't retrieve a unique user token from it. You could always take a username/password through a custom web form and then pass it to the API and use the username + receipt of a token to validate a successful logon. That's not a perfect solution but I think that's a s close as you'll get using the existing functionality.